# this.$root.$emit not working in Vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want to emit an event on the root component, and listen to in in the root component. In a child of child component I do this:

```
this.$root.$emit('access-token', accessToken);
```

In root component (the top component, first to load) I do this (edit: this is in the mounted() method):

```
this.$on('access-token', this.setAccessToken);
```

It doesn't react to the event though. Why?

Comment: you tagged this Vue &Vue 2, are you using Vue 2?

Comment: Yes, vue2, sorry

Comment: Curious, if you put a listener elsewhere does it work? For instance if you put the listener one level up from where you're emitting it rather than the root does is get triggered properly? I would make sure that you're broadcasting correctly first then dig into your listeners.

Comment: Yes it does work elsewhere.

Comment: If I do this.$root.$on in the component where I emit the event, then the handler gets called, but if I add the handler in mounted() in the root component it doesn't work.

Comment: How many layers deep is your nested component? This $root approach is eerily similar to Angular 1. I did just find this article that said Vue emits only go up one level, so you may need to bump up more. https://forum.vuejs.org/t/recommended-approach-to-emit-an-event-from-a-nested-child/10197/2

Comment: Also, from experience in Angular 1, this is exactly why folks use Redux.

Answer (score 45):

You are not using the `$root` for the event `$on`

Change this:

```
this.$on('access-token', this.setAccessToken);
```

for this:

```
this.$root.$on('access-token', this.setAccessToken);
```

Comment: Seems worth mentioning that it appears vue is not encouraging this kind of approach, and suggests a dummy component as an event bus or vuex-

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced

Comment: I am using 
```this.$root.$on('map-doc', function(control) {
   console.log(this.brushSize); //this.addMapControlText(control);
  });```
in a component's mounted block.
Why I am not able to get the value of this.dataElement inside this?

Answer (score 1):

I've to use the following approach:

```
mounted() {
  this.$nuxt.$emit('event-name')
}
```

```
mounted() {
  this.$nuxt.$on('event-name', () =>
    ...
  }
}
```

Using Nuxt 2.14