# How i can emit event from directive by click outside of element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can't understand how to emit event from directive

This is my template where i try to call method :

```
<tooltip v-click-outside="clickEvent" v-on:emitedEvent="clickEvent"></tooltip>
```

From v-click-outside="clickEvent" i got:

```
Property or method "clickEvent" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

My code:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clickEvent: function () {
      console.log('click')
    }
  },
}
Vue.directive('click-outside', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.event = function (event) {
      if (!(el.contains(event.target))) {
          vnode.context.$emit('emitedEvent')
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', el.event)
  },
  unbind: function (el) {
    document.removeEventListener('click', el.event)
  },
})
```

I get:

```
Invalid handler for event "emitedEvent": got undefined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problems you're encountering are primarily based on two problems:

1. the level at which you're defining the functions
2. camel case custom events are not supported (always use kebab case - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names)

Check out the following fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/chrismarx/gvrsmj1y/7/

Note that using this template:

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>directive test</h2>
  <component-a v-on:emited-event="parentClickEvent"></component-a> 
</div>
```

1. The root component has to define the parentClickEvent method, since the event is being emitted from component-a. You also need to emit the event from within component-a

```
  template:'<button type="button" @click="clickEvent" v-click-outside>test</button>',
```

or use the $root object for emitting and listening for events at the same level ( [this.$root.$emit not working in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50181858/this-root-emit-not-working-in-vue) )

2. The $emit call should broadcast a kebab cased event, otherwise the event won't get picked up -