# Vue event handler, shared between all components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have create a new Vue instance and assigned it to my window, which should give me access to it throughout all components. This should give me access to events emitted anywhere within my application.

However for some reason this is not the case, can someone advise me?

**app.js**

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
window.events = new Vue();
window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: {
        emit: function (name, params) {
            window.events.$emit(name, params);
        }
    }
});
```

I have created a `emit` method within my app for my components to use, as simply calling `v-on:change="window.events.$emit('makeChanged', $event)"` was not working, I was getting the error that `window` is not defined.

I'm listening for any emitted events from the `emit` within my component as follows:

```
window.events.$on('makeChanged', function(evt) {});
```

**Edit:**

Still can't get this working...

`app.js`

```
Vue.component('models-select', require('./components/results-text/ModelsSelect.vue'));

window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: {
        emit(name, ...params) {
            this.$root.$emit(name, ...params);
        },
    ...
```

`ModelsSelect.vue`

```
export default {
        props: [ 'endpoint', 'makeId', 'modelId', 'typeId'],
        mounted() {

            this.$root.$on('make-changed', function(evt) {
                console.log(evt);
            });
```

Within one of my views (add.blade.php)

```
<select name="make" id="makes" v-on:change="emit('make-changed', $event)" tabindex="2" class="{{ old('make') ? ' is-changed' : '' }}">
```

Comment: Can you try changing your emit to `this.$root.$emit` and your listener to `this.$root.$on`?

Comment: @Lewis no luck, if I add a created method to the instance of Vue, and listen for the event there it works, however the component is not picking the event up.

Comment: Odd. I know it's not an answer to your question but it seems to be recommended to use an [Event Bus](https://medium.com/easyread/vue-as-event-bus-life-is-happier-7a04fe5231e1) for stuff like this. The [VueJS Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50181858/this-root-emit-not-working-in-vue) seem to consider this an edge case. Mentioned in a comment on that link.

Comment: Why not use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for this... Kick of an action vs emitting events, and listen for those events in your components via watchers..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can emit and listen events with `$root` element.

```js
methods: {
    emit(name, ...args) {
        this.$root.$emit(name, ...args)
    }
}
```

In components:

```js
mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('event-name', this.handleEvent)
},
beforeDestroy() {
    this.$root.$off('event-name', this.handleEvent)
},
methods: {
    handleEvent() {
        // handle event (with optional args)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this solution better then using event-bus?

Comment: I was using an event bus before but i didn't want to keep on importing an additional file into all my components which use it

Comment: @MartynBall, install Vue.js devtools and check emitted events.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `window` in `v-on:`:

[API docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on):

> The expression can be a method name, an inline statement, or omitted if there are modifiers present.

To do what you want to do you should move access to `window.events` to the method:

```html
<some-element v-on:change="globalEmit('makeChanged', $event)" />
```

```js
{
  methods: {
    globalEmit(name, ...params) {
      window.events.$emit(name, ...params);
    }
  }
}
```

Then,  you can move this `globalEmit` method to the [global mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin), rename it to `$gemit` (for example) and use it everywhere like this:

```html
<some-element v-on:change="$gemit('makeChanged', $event)" />
```

Comment: @MartynBall In this edit you're using `$root`, not another window Vue instance.